# How to get last quarter and last year values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with data 'per quarters'.

I would like to have the value of the previous quarter and the value 4 quarters before (1 year before) next to my quarter value.

What is the best way to do it:

- Tranform into dates
- Play with the order of the data and the indexes?

I can create a specific funtion to do it but it will be slow and dirty

Data example:

```
date    store    value
2014Q4    A        100
2014Q3    A        90
2014Q2    A        80
2014Q1    A        70
2013Q4    A        110
2013Q3    A        60    
2013Q2    A        80
```

And I want this:

```
date    store    value   previous_q   previous_y
2014Q4    A        100     90            110
2014Q3    A        90      80            60
2014Q2    A        80      70            80 
2014Q1    A        70     110             :
2013Q4    A        110     60
2013Q3    A        60      80
2013Q2    A        80      :
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Shift.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

```
import pandas as pd

index = ['14Q1','14Q2','14Q3','14Q4','15Q1']
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(16,21),'B':range(11,16)},index=index)

df['C'] = df.B.shift(1)
df['D'] = df.B.shift(4)

       A   B   C   D
14Q1  16  11 NaN NaN
14Q2  17  12  11 NaN
14Q3  18  13  12 NaN
14Q4  19  14  13 NaN
15Q1  20  15  14  11
```

EDIT: Removed fillna(0). Makes sense to keep NA's.